# cannot load such file -- oauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth

I'm getting the following error:
cannot load such file -- oauth
in a RoR application. What I've done:
-Installed the oauth gem
-Added **gem 'oauth'** to my gemfile
-Run **bundle install**
-Run **rake** a million times
-Checked to make sure oauth was installed via the **gem list** command

I should add that I am running Ruby 1.9.3 and that rails works fine when I don't try to use OAuth.

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace of the error?

Comment: All I can get is this: app/controllers/application_controller.rb:4:in `<top (required)>'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   oauth